# How to use only select properties from a backend for use in an ngrx store

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I am beginning to implement ngrx into a new enterprise angular application.  I am loading data into the store with a simple effect that makes a service call
 `@Effect()
  loadCheckin$ = this.actions$.ofType(checkInActions.LOAD_CHECK_IN)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.checkInService.getCheckIn()
          .pipe(
            map(checkIn => {
              return new checkInActions.LoadCheckInSuccess(checkIn)}),
            catchError(error => of(new checkInActions.LoadCheckInFail(error)))
          );
      })
    );`

The response from the server which this returns to my success action is a large object containing many properties I don't need for my frontend store.

I'd like a frontend state interface something like this:

```
export interface AppointmentState {
checkIn: fromCheckIn.CheckInState;
action: fromAction.ActionState;
billing: fromBilling.BillingState;
clinical: fromClinical.ClinicalState;
documents: fromDocuments.DocumentsState;
```

};

Each of these slices of state have their own interfaces. All this is structured based on what the frontend needs, not what the backend looks like.

What I'm struggling to understand is the way we match up the data between the backend and the frontend. When I'm loading up that huge object from the backend, even though I only need a few of the properties, is the reducer the correct place to create and return something that is properly constructed for the state? Is there any reason to keep a state that exactly matches the backend response? Are there any other best practices around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two popular guides:
https://redux.js.org/
https://gist.github.com/btroncone/a6e4347326749f938510

> When I'm loading up that huge object from the backend, even though I only need a few of the properties, is the reducer the correct place to create and return something that is properly constructed for the state?

From https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html

> Reducers specify how the application's state changes in response to actions sent to the store.

Sometimes the action has an associated payload that is used to modify state. When loading data from the DB I find that this often means transforming the data to the shape that you want. So the reducers are a fine place to do transformations.

Often I will do some mapping in my API layer to some intermediate model or even to the state model and the reducer will mostly just set, add, remove, or replace. This is because I have other actions in the app that will modify that same slice of state and I don't want to have multiple actions that do the same thing with different payloads or to map user data to the shape of the API DTOs just to update state. It depends on your needs but you can do it before or in your reducers. You are likely to have additional transformations in your projections as you map to view models.

> Is there any reason to keep a state that exactly matches the backend response?

I can't think of a good reason to. You may not have to transform it but that depends on the shape of your data and what shape you want in the app. The needs of your app should drive the shape of your state. It is important to normalize your data for ease of updating and selecting and to avoid unwanted change notifications.

Here is a good reference on normalizing state: https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html
Here is some documentation on the ngrx entities feature that you may want to use to reduce some of the boilerplate:
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/entity/README.md

Comment: Thank you for the thorough and informative answer @bygrace .